# azcopy error specifying multiple file patterns is not supported

Tags: azcopy

I am getting this error on azcopy ;the command syntax in incorrect
azcopy error specifying multiple file patterns is not supported
my command   azcopy   myfile.csv  kobosh.blob.core/mycontainer/destkey:key axkey.txt

any one have idea or  encountered this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to upload myfile.csv  or axkey.txt?

The tools stopped to support multiple file pattern since 2.5 due to performance considerationg: http://ppe.blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/08/azcopy-2-5-release.aspx

Additionally, per the help (run 'AzCopy /?') its input format is:

```
AzCopy source destination [filepattern] [options]
```

source and dest are both "containers", in your case it should be local folder. and you need to put the option after the the pattern, as well as your URL should be correct, so it might be :

```
azcopy <the folder of your file> https://kobosh.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer <your file name> /destkey:key
```